# view tag return 0 value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing strange issue with tag value in my iOS Project for iPad

**I have given diiferent subviews of my view some tags 1,2,3,4,5.... in interface builder**

but when I am trying to get tag value dynamically it is given me 0 value.

```
NSArray *pSubviews = [self.view subviews];

    // Enumerate the portrait view
    for (int sv = 0; sv < [pSubviews count]; sv++)
    {

        UIView *pObject = (id)[pSubviews objectAtIndex : sv];
        NSLog(@"tag %d",pObject.tag);
    }
```

**result**

```
2016-05-07 22:12:58.832[1562:47169] tag 0
2016-05-07 22:12:58.832[1562:47169] tag 0
2016-05-07 22:12:58.832[1562:47169] tag 0
2016-05-07 22:12:58.832[1562:47169] tag 0
2016-05-07 22:12:58.832[1562:47169] tag 0
2016-05-07 22:12:58.832[1562:47169] tag 0
```

I am setting my view dynamically for iPad view in app delegate launch method.

```
 myViewController *ldVC;
    if (IS_IPAD)
    {
        ldVC = [[myViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    }
    else
    {
        ldVC = [[myViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];

    }
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ldVC];
    self.window.rootViewController=navVC;
```

view hierarchy::

[image]

Comment: so I have to set in both nib even if iPad view is called ? that is what you wantto say?

Comment: because I set tag for iPad view.

Comment: ohk let me try it quick . I will tell you if it will work @matt

Comment: I set tag to both iPad and iPhone nib . not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view probably has not set if you are running this in the viewDidLoad method. Try running it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: may be .I am setting this in viewdidload only. I think this should be the case. let me try @penatheboss

Comment: you are right. I called method with some delay and now i get tags . thanks @penatheboss.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @matt thanks. The same thing has happened to me several times, and I was glad I could help out.